# Permanently set DB2CLP environment variable

Tags: db2

I have a problem with DB2CLP environment variable, on Windows 7 64, IBM_client64_V97 (to be connected with DB2).

Every time when i try to DB2 in Windows command prompt window, I receive this error:

DB21061E  Command line environment not initialized.

and per [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237966) document using just this step:

```
2. at the prompt enter these commands:
db2cmd -i -w db2clpsetcp 
echo %DB2CLP%
```

I fix that error, and "db2" command opens Command Line Processor for DB2 Client.
But it lasts only until windows CMD is open. As soon as I close it and reopen, I have to repeat process.

My question (being absolute novice to DB2) is:

1. How should I make that change permanent and
2. How this happened at the first place as I installed and setup everything according to the manual (including adding local user to DB2USERS and DB2ADMINS) groups?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just start your command prompt with `db2cmd` (which opens a command prompt with everything initialized for you) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When DB2 client is installed, it should have installed a functional window to the command line processor.  Check here:

Start / All Programs / IBM DB2 / DB2copy1/ Command Line Processor

Note that DB2copy1 is the default location for the first db2 instance.  The name may be different if user select the non-default name.

Shortcut to the CLP can be copied on the desktop.

Regarding the typing "DB2 ..some command..." in windows command prompt which causes described error explanation is as follows:

> That's because the normal DOS (or Windows) prompt doesn't
>   automatically run the setup script that enables the DB2 commands. 
>   When the setup runs, it puts the DB2 items first in the PATH variable.
>   That could conflict with other tools that also want to be first on the
>   search list.
>
> If you've got both the DOS (Windows) and DB2 command line prompts on
>   your desktop, right click them and select Properties.  You'll notice
>   that the system (DOS) prompt runs cmd.exe.
>
> The DB2 prompt runs DB2CMD.exe from the DB2 libraries.  The DB2 script
>   then runs DB2SETCP.BAT and finally DB2.EXE.  (All of the DB2
>   executables should be in C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN.)
>
> So there are differences in the two prompts.  For you purposes, try
>   running DB2SETCP.BAT from the normal DOS prompt.  That may be
>   sufficient for your needs.
>
> For my purposes I always have the DOS and DB2 prompts on my desktop
>   and just select the one that I need.

Comment: running DB2SETCP.BAT before running any db2 command worked for me

Comment: Same here DB2SETUP batch file did the work for me. It setup the env variable that I can echo %DB2CLP%